# User follow query that fetches the first top post for each user being follow

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6

I have built a user follow mechanism.

I have a table of posts:

- id (int)
- post (varchar)
- when (DateTime)

table of users

- id
- name

table of following:

- id (int)
- user_id (int)
- follow_user_id (int)

I want to present the user the top first post for each user based on the date (Descending) and the query should result in a list that holds a pair of post/user based on a user Id parameter. The User Id is the 'user_id' in table 'following', so I can display the post and the user data in a table for a particular 'user_id' follower.

So if the user is following 50 users and if all those users have many posts, it will return 1 latest post for each user, so the query will return 50 results paired with the Post and User data.

I am in a need for an optimized query for that in Linq or Entity Framework.

Using ASP.NET 4.5 / C# / Entity Framework 6 / Visual Studio 2015

Answer (score 0):

```
select top(1) post
from posts P
join 3rdTABLE T on P.ID= T.ID
where T.user_id='123456'        
order by when DESC
```

In above you can pass @User_ID as parameter or declare @User_ID BIGINT and change

```
  **where T.user_id='123456'**
```

To

```
  **where T.user_id=@user_id**
```

Comment: My bad for not mentioning Linq or Entity framework, I need that type of query. Also it would return many post, for each  user being followed.